# How to find which player will win

Tags: algorithm

Two players play the following game. At the beginning of the game they start with n (1<=n<=100000) piles of stones. At each step of the game, the player chooses a pile and remove at least one stone from this pile and move zero or more stones from this pile to any other pile that still has stones. A player loses if he has no more possible moves. Given the initial piles, determine who wins: the first player, or the second player, if both play perfectly.

Comment: help me out .... i have tried this question a lot but not able to find correct answer yet

Comment: Have you tried solving the case n = 2?  What about the case n = 3?

Comment: This is a famous problem known as bean game...and goes back to many years ago. It was a match in England that was solved. You would search on Google. If you do not find the solution of this issue, You could contact me in order to help you.

Comment: guidance : Change all the sizes of the heaps into binary. Add each individual place. Make sure each place has an even number left after each of your turns. This should be done after every turn. This is worded a bit vaguely, so here's a sample game. You need to go first in order to win.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim). Understanding the solution to Nim should help you understand this game better.

For Nim, the game begins with `n` piles of stones. In turn, each player chooses one pile and removes at least one, possibly more, stone from the pile. The game ends when there are no more stones remaining.

The wikipedia article linked above has a nice explanation of the winning strategy, which involves computing the binary digital sum of the pile sizes. Read up on that, and you should be able to solve this variant.

Answer (score 0):

First start off by analyzing the positions with known outcome - that would be the case when all stones are in a single pile. Then you have no other pile with at least one stone so you can not perform the second part of the move(this is assuming that even when you move 0 stones there still has to be another non-empty pile) so this is loosing position.

Now start analyzing from which positions can you get to the loosing positions. These will be your first round of winning positions.

First observation: as a move only affects two piles it is obvious that you can get to the loosing position only if you have exactly two piles. If you have only two piles you can always get to the loosing position by removing all the stones from one of them and thus this is a winning position.

So now you have to think about which are the positions that force you to make a move taking you to the found winning position. These again will be loosing positions(tip: I believe this is only the case where you have 3 piles with 1 stone each).

Continue this way and in the end you will come up with the final solution. I do not want to solve the whole problem for you as this will be of no good for your skills. Better come up with the solution on your own.

Hope this helps.

NOTE: if you are allowed to perform operations on a single non-empty pile i.e. if when moving zero stones you don't need another non-empty pile, then the initial loosing position is when you have no stones left at all and the initial winning position is when you have only one pile with any number of stones.

Comment: "move *zero* or more stones from this pile to any other pile". So multiple piles with 1 stone each is not a losing position.

Comment: hmm I must have misread this one - I thought it is at least one. Will edit my post accordingly